# Monitoring nginx (500's) with telegraf

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, telegraf, telegraf-inputs-plugin, nginx-status

I'd like to understand what my nginx instance is returning and who it's asking to handle requests.  What fraction of my queries get handled by rails, what fraction are handled directly by nginx, what fraction are heading off to nginx_status, etc.

Similarly, I'd also like to understand things like how many of which HTTP result codes I'm returning.  If there's a peak in 500's, I'd like to know.

The [telegraf nginx plugin](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/nginx) provides some very basic stats on nginx but no more.  I've seen some vaguely complicated solutions for result codes that basically involve setting up log monitoring infrastructure.  This data seems so fundamental I feel I must be missing something.

I've seen nothing that will help me understand *who* is actually handling queries (i.e., which handler).

All of this is interesting because (1) secular growth in handler dispatches can indicate scaling issues in clearer ways than simple load on the handler machines, and (2) peaks in anything can alert to problems.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

If it's actual I would like to write my own config. It based on tail telegraf plugin.

1. Add speshial log format to http section

```
    log_format codes_combined 'code=$status ts=$time_iso8601';
```

2. Use this format in server section

```
    access_log /var/log/nginx/codes.log codes_combined;
```

3. Edit /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf:

```
[[inputs.tail]]
    files = ["/var/log/nginx/codes.log"]
    data_format = "logfmt"
```

4. After restart nginx and telegrap data should be avalable in Graphana. I configured a new graph [image]

```
SELECT count("code") as code_2xx FROM "tail" WHERE $timeFilter AND code >= 200 AND code < 300 AND code  <> 204  GROUP BY time($__interval)
SELECT count("code") as  code_3xx  FROM "tail" WHERE $timeFilter AND code >= 300 AND code < 400 GROUP BY time($__interval)
SELECT count("code") as  code_4xx  FROM "tail" WHERE $timeFilter AND code >= 400 AND code < 500 GROUP BY time($__interval)
SELECT count("code") as  code_5xx  FROM "tail" WHERE $timeFilter AND code >= 500  GROUP BY time($__interval)
SELECT count("code") as code_204 FROM "tail" WHERE $timeFilter AND  code  = 204  GROUP BY time($__interval)
```

5. Don't forger to check  /etc/logrotate.d/nginx. Permisions should be like this:

```
create 0644 www-data adm
```

Answer (score 0):

You can let telegraf collect your nginx access logs. Then you can analyze how many requests had which HTTP status code (1xx, 2xx, etc).

Add this to your `/etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf` (and make sure telegraf has access rights to the logfile, it won't tell you, if it hasn't):

```
[[inputs.logparser]]
   files = ["/var/log/nginx/access.log"]
   from_beginning = true
   name_override = "nginx_access_log"

   [inputs.logparser.grok]
     patterns = ["%{COMBINED_LOG_FORMAT}"]
     measurement = "nginx_access_log"
```

Comment: Logparser has since been deprecated. This is still useful for reference (and it still works for now, I just wouldn't start _new_ setups with it).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to modify the permissions of files under the /var/log/nginx/ directory, you can try using the following command:

sudo chmod 777 /var/log/nginx/*

By running this command with superuser privileges (sudo), you will grant read, write, and execute permissions to all users (owner, group, and others) for all files within the /var/log/nginx/ directory.

Please exercise caution when using chmod 777 as it grants full permissions to all users, which may have security implications. It is generally recommended to set more restrictive permissions based on your specific requirements and security guidelines.

Before proceeding, ensure that modifying the permissions of the files under /var/log/nginx/ is necessary and aligns with your intended use case or troubleshooting needs.