# Storing response time and no of requests in influxdb from access logs

Tags: monitoring, influxdb, logparser, telegraf, telegraf-plugins

I have got a requirement to fetch and store response time and count of different 2xx,4xx and 5xx request from access logs to influxdb.(for graphing and alerting purpose).

I know I can use telegraf to parse logs file and keep sending data to influxdb. And get these counts from running query on the data.

[[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49450336/monitoring-nginx-500s-with-telegraf), [2](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/issues/3991) ]

But in this way, I will be sending a lot of datapoints to the influxbd server.

What I am trying to find is, if there is any way, I can only send processed data to influxdb, like no of req/sec, no of 2xx/4xx/5xx req/sec.

I have been reading on various threads and blogs, but couldn't find anything matching.

Anyhelp would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`"c:\Program Files (x86)\Log Parser 2.2\LogParser.exe"`

```
SELECT sc-status, COUNT(*) FROM [logfile] 
GROUP BY sc-status
```

you can add the math on select statement to calculate /sec responses.